# How to run Vue 3/Vite app in library mode for test/demo purposes?

Tags: javascript, npm, vuejs3, vite

I am trying to create Vue 3 components library as a npm package using Vite.js. I have configured Vite accordingly to [the docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#library-mode). It works, but I need to test my library somehow.

Before I created libraries with [vue-sfc-rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sfc-rollup) and it has special script and folder for that purpose.

package.json (in vue-sfc-rollup):

```
"scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve dev/serve.ts"
....
```

And in that folder:

```
dev/
    serve.ts
    serve.vue
```

serve.ts:

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import Dev from './serve.vue';

const app = createApp(Dev);
app.mount('#app');
```

Which is creates a small SPA for testing/demo.

I am trying to achieve something similar to this with Vite. Any ideas?

UPD:

So, the question probably is how to specify certain main.js file while running Vite?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-vite-to-publish-a-vue-component-to-npm-7043a56cfa00). You will not need `vue-sfc-rollup` anymore while you are using `Vite`. `Vite` uses rollup behind the scence.